# Join If Exists in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm running a report that exports the information for members of committees into an excel spreadsheet.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT membership_organization.name AS Firm, 
membership_individual.first AS FirstName, 
membership_individual.middle AS MiddleName, 
membership_individual.last AS LastName, 
membership_individual.email AS Email, 
membership_individual.phone AS Phone, 
membership_location.addr1 AS Address1, 
membership_location.addr2 AS Address2, 
membership_location.city AS City, 
membership_location.state AS State, 
membership_location.zipcode AS Zip 
FROM membership_individual 
JOIN membership_organization ON membership_individual.org_name_id = membership_organization.id 
JOIN membership_location ON membership_individual.location_id = membership_location.id 
WHERE membership_individual.id IN ({list if ids}) 
ORDER BY LastName
```

The problem is some of the members don't have a location id set, or it's set to 0, so those members don't show up in the report.

Is there a way I can qualify the location JOIN? If the members location id exists pull the info, if not show me the info that is available.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Change both of your `JOIN`s into `LEFT JOIN`s.  You'll get all your records from membership_individual where the where clause matches, and NULL values for the other tables where rows don't match.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was something easy, guess I need some coffee. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT membership_organization.name AS Firm, 
membership_individual.first AS FirstName, 
membership_individual.middle AS MiddleName, 
membership_individual.last AS LastName, 
membership_individual.email AS Email, 
membership_individual.phone AS Phone, 
membership_location.addr1 AS Address1, 
membership_location.addr2 AS Address2, 
membership_location.city AS City, 
membership_location.state AS State, 
membership_location.zipcode AS Zip 
FROM membership_individual 
JOIN membership_organization ON membership_individual.org_name_id = membership_organization.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN membership_location ON membership_individual.location_id = membership_location.id 
WHERE membership_individual.id IN ({list if ids}) 
ORDER BY LastName
```

Comment: `outer` is implied.  `left join` is all that is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Use left join, meaning your query will become

```
SELECT membership_organization.name AS Firm, 
membership_individual.first AS FirstName, 
membership_individual.middle AS MiddleName, 
membership_individual.last AS LastName, 
membership_individual.email AS Email, 
membership_individual.phone AS Phone, 
membership_location.addr1 AS Address1, 
membership_location.addr2 AS Address2, 
membership_location.city AS City, 
membership_location.state AS State, 
membership_location.zipcode AS Zip 
FROM membership_individual 
JOIN membership_organization ON membership_individual.org_name_id = membership_organization.id 
LEFT JOIN membership_location ON membership_individual.location_id = membership_location.id 
WHERE membership_individual.id IN ({list if ids}) 
ORDER BY LastName
```

and you'll get the data for all members, even the ones for whom there are no rows in the location table.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
LEFT JOIN membership_location ON membership_individual.location_id = membership_location.id
```

instead of your variant..